# Excel macros missing after transferring the file from a friend

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I sent a friend an Excel file which contained some macros.

She made some changes and sent it back to me, but somehow the macros have been removed.

Could it be possible that some file scanner or anti virus program removed the macros? Is there anyway I can verify?

Comment: Please be more explicit.  Were the macros in an addin, were they VBA code in the workbook, or something else?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using and are they using? And if you have 2007 or later, did you save the file as a macro-enabled file (.xlsm)?

Answer (score 2):

First, check the file extension. If it's XLS or XLSX, it's likely that she saved her changes to another file and didn't choose "macro-enabled workbook" (file extension: XLSM) while saving it.

[image]

It's also possible that your friend doesn't have macros enabled in Excel.

Here's how you can confirm it in MS Excel 2007:

1. Press Alt > F > I
2. Go to Trust Center > Trust Center Settings.
3. Select either the 3rd or 4th option.